# Como hacer funcionar un combobox con un if

Tags: java, netbeans

como puedo usar un if comparativo con un combo box de item, si quiero que al puslar un boton me dibujo un a figura geometrica[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Te recomiendo que copies y pegues tu codigo, no agregues imagenes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar aquello, primero deberías crear un listener.

El listener te dirá que el usuario eligió una opción del combobox, esto es:

```
combo.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        comboActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});
```

Luego, dentro de la función `comboActionPerformed`, puedes identificar cuál fue la opción seleccionada y a partir de allí tomar una decisión.

En tu caso, te recomendaría utilizar un switch, si selecciono la opción 1, que haga una tarea, si selecciono la opción 2, otra, y así.

```
private void comboActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    switch (combo.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            // Dibujar rectangulo
            break;
        case 1:
            // Dibujar circulo
            break;
        case 2:
            // Dibujar línea
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias colega, si me funcionó...francodi65

Comment: De nada, me alegro que haya funcionado. No olvides de marcar como respuesta satisfactoria. Saludos